# Create Array from table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create an array using jQuery from a table with a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>`

The result I am looking for is

`[[20th Jan, 33], [21st Jan, 44], [22nd Jan, 5],[23rd Jan, 17]]`

My Table is as follows

```
<table class="" id="bookedTable" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>20th jan</th>
        <th>21st jan</th>
        <th>22nd jan</th>
        <th>23rd Jan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>17</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My JS is as follows

```
$(function() {
var $table = $("#bookedTable"),
  $headerCells = $table.find("thead th"),
  $rowCells = $table.find("tbody tr td");

var headers = [],
  rows = [];

$headerCells.each(function(k,v) {
 headers[headers.length] = $(this).text();
});

$rowCells.each(function(k,v) {
 rows[rows.length] = $(this).text();
});

console.log(headers);
console.log(rows);
});
```

I can only figure out how to console log the header and rows sepeartely and not combine them in 1 array per my desired result above. Looking for some help to resolve.

[**MY DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kp7zK/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = $.map($('#bookedTable th:not(:first)'), function(el,i) {
    return [[$(el).text(), $('#bookedTable td:eq('+i+')').text()]];
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4LFuZ/1/)

Comment: Very nice code, one suggestion though.  You could pass the index as the second argument to `map` function, eliminating the need for `$(el).index()`

Comment: @KevinBowersox - That's true, didn't think of that when I was typing. Added!

Comment: thanks a lot, that is a nice bit of code. 1 thing I just realised is that my code is now giving out as there is no date object returned. Is it possible in the array (and sorry I know this is an addition) that you can return the date field in the th as a date object in the array?  thanks and sorry for late follow up..

Comment: Not to sound like a poor sport for having the correct answer taken away, but isn't this just a jQuery exercise answer? Using a standard JS for loop and array push is just as easy to read, as well as more efficient. Not saying that it isn't nice code, but everything has its place in complexity.

Comment: @ChrisDixon - Sure, it's just another way of writing the code and getting the same result etc. dystroy answered this correctly first, yet you got all the upvotes and I got the accepted answer (for now). It happens all the time to all of us, and it's annoying, but it's up to the OP to accept the answer he decided to use, and everyone else to upvote the correct answers etc. and hopefully they make the right choices.

Comment: @Redwall - You're right, it's not a date object, just a string. `20th jan` isn't really a valid date, but assuming the year should always be set to the current year you could create a date object.

Comment: sorry guys did not want to get into all the politics of accepted answer etc. I actually originally choose ChrisDixon but when I put it in my code it did not work correctly, it was returing html for the first part of the array. I decided to try this code instead due to the positive comments from Kevin and it worked right away, hence I thought this was best. I up-voted all the answers and things were happening fast to know who posted first. Sorry if that was not the way I was supposed to pick the answer, but I did choose the one that worked for me right away..

Comment: @Redwall - You're free to pick whatever answer you like, it's totally up to you, don't sweat it. It's just a little annoying sometimes when you're scrambling to post an answer, and then an answer posted ten minutes later is accepted, but again, you're the one who picks an answer, and whatever works for you is the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
var combined = [];  

for(var i = 1; i < $headerCells.length; i++) {
    combined.push([$($headerCells[i]).text(), $($rowCells[i]).text()]);
}
```

See it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kp7zK/2/

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to separately pick the headers (this replaces the whole code) :

```
var $table = $("#bookedTable"), l = [];
$table.find('thead th').each(function(i){
 l.push([$(this).text(), $('table tbody td').eq(i).text()])
});
l = l.slice(1);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/pTA3L/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArr = [];
$("table thead tr th").each(function(i){
    if(i != 0){
        var colValue = $("table tbody tr td").eq(i).text();
        myArr.push([this.innerHTML, colValue]);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FtK4b/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
   var rows = [];
   $('tbody tr td').each(function(k,v) {
     if(k>0)
          rows.push([ $('thead th:eq('+k+')').text(),$(this).text()]);
   });
   alert(rows.toSource());
});
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kp7zK/5/)